# A way to convert view commands to its corresponding html(like irb or ruby script/console)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to see view code converted to html other than starting project and view the page source? In Rails development environment, we can use code and see what it returns, but it would have been nice if we were able to do something like this.

```
<< @user = User.all.map { |user| [user.name, user.id] }
=> [["Patrick", 1], ["Greg", 2]]
<< select_tag "user", @user, {}, :tab_index => "5"
=> "<select id=\"user\" name=\"user\" tab_index=\"5\"><option value=\"1\">Patrick</option>
<option value=\"2\">Greg</option>"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Rails 3, you can access these helpers via `helper`.

```
$ rails console
>> helper.select_tag "user"
=> "<select id=\"user\" name=\"user\"></select>"
>> helper.submit_tag "goodbye"
=> "<input name=\"commit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"goodbye\" />"
```